# Como solucionar el problema de no se puede resolver el símbolo en Android estudio?

Tags: java, android-studio

Estoy ocupando Android studio 4.2 y me encuentro desarrollando aplicaciones con lenguaje java para impresoras hp que tengan work path, el asunto es que implemente la librería de work path y no me reconoce la parte final de de la importación y no e podido arreglarlo.

ahora adjunto parte del código: en el import no me reconoce solo el workpath

```html
import com.hp.workpath.api.Workpath; 

@Override
    protected InitStatus doInBackground(final Void... params) {
        InitStatus status = InitStatus.NO_ERROR;

        try {
            // initialize Workpath SDK
            Workpath.getInstance().initialize(mContextRef.get());

            // Check if SuppliesService is supported
            if (!SuppliesService.isSupported(mContextRef.get())) {
                // SuppliesService is not supported on this device
                status = InitStatus.NOT_SUPPORTED;
            }
        } catch (SsdkUnsupportedException sue) {
            mThrowable = sue;
            status = InitStatus.INIT_EXCEPTION;
        } catch (SecurityException se) {
            mThrowable = se;
            status = InitStatus.INIT_EXCEPTION;
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            mThrowable = t;
            status = InitStatus.INIT_EXCEPTION;
        }

        return status;
    }
```

ahora mostrare como implemente la librería: fue la única forma que me pudo funcionar la implementación sin que arrojara error

```js
dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'

    implementation files('libs\\WorkpathLib-javadoc.jar')
```

Answer (score 0):

Sigue los siguientes pasos:

1. Importa la libreria tal cual como la deberías.
2. Navega hacia el Menu File (o menu de archivo).
3. Haz click en Invalidate Caches/Restart (o Invalidar Cache/Reiniciar).
4. Finalmente haz click en Invalidate and Restart (Invalidar Cache/Reiniciar).

Espera a que se reinicie y se reconstruya el proyecto y listo!

Comment: gracias por la ayuda pero no me funciono, tendrá que ver con esto? Unused import statement

Comment: Simplemente lo que te esta diciendo es que no estas usando la importacion, no creo pero en principio con lo anterior debió de funcionar. Pero podria ser que no la estes agregando correctament.

Comment: Recuerda que tienes que crearte un folder dentro de App "libs" y que tenga el mismo nombre de la implementación.

Comment: lo voy a intentar amigo gracias por responder, mira asi es como lo implementa un codigo ejemplo y no se por que en el mio me da error al momento de implementar

Comment: implementation project(':WorkpathLib')

Comment: Si no sabes como importar la libreria externa mira este [tutorial](https://o7planning.org/10525/how-to-add-external-libraries-to-android-project-in-android-studio)

Comment: bacan amigo ahora veré bien el tutorial que se ve bien completo, se agradece la ayuda

Comment: ultima consulta amigo, sabes como se implementaría un botón que envie los datos que quiero llamar, en este caso serian los datos de los contadores

Comment: no funciono ningun metodo amigo sigo con el mismo error

Comment: Trata de simular que vas a utilizar la misma libreria en un nuevo mini  proyecto, siguiendo el tutorial anterior paso a paso y comprueba si funciona.